# Port(hardware) addressing in linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I am new to linux.I am learning to write driver .
 Can any one tell me how to address to a port of computer and how to control it like listening through it ,make device sleep and other functions.
 I have not written any code yet as i am afraid that it may damage my pc's h/w.
 Any help will be apreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Are you very familiar with C programming, and with user-land Linux application programming (see [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)? If not, learn both first. Don't write kernel code (e.g. drivers) if you are new to Linux.

Comment: thank you i know c programming not that familiar with linux appliation programming i will try to learn that thanks for link